# Visual Basic MacroSolve Loop error - Data only populates for last row and I want only roundup whole variables returned

Tags: excel, loops, solver, vba

Below is my code and I have having two major issues:

1. I want the change variables to be only whole values (rounded up) (ex: a patient only needs x amount of drug but package sizes are set amounts and remaining drug is wasted, I can't use 1 and half vials of drug, I must use 2 vials).
2. My code only populates for the bottom row (36) and not at row count 25 where my data begins

```
Sub MacroSolve()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Rowcount = 25
Do While Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & Rowcount))
 SolverReset
 SolverOptions precision:=0.001
 SolverOk SetCell:="$H$" & Rowcount, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$E$" & Rowcount & ":$F$" & Rowcount


SolverAdd CellRef:="$E$" & Rowcount, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$F$" & Rowcount, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"

SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$" & Rowcount, Relation:=3, FormulaText:=Range("$D$" & Rowcount)

SolverAdd CellRef:="$H$" & Rowcount, Relation:=3, FormulaText:=Range("$F$21")

SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
SolverFinish keepFinal:=1
Rowcount = Rowcount + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue you have is an easy one. In order for it to always display whole amounts of pill containers or whatever you simply need to add 0.5 to the number and use something like this:

```
Dim packageSize As Integer

packageSize = WorksheetFunction.Round(3.1 + 0.5, 0) 'Replace 3.1 with whatever value you will be using/with a cell reference
```

You can test it with any number and you will see that it works (ex: 3.9999 + 0.5 will return 4. And 3.0001 +0.5 will also return 4)

Now the second issue you, if you are looping through cells I would recommend using a `For Loop` instead of a `Do Loop`

```
Dim workingCell as Range
Dim workingRange as Range
dim i as long

'This finds the last row in which you have data (assuming nothing goes beyond row 500,000)
i = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D500000").End(xlUp).Row
Set workingRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D25:D" & i)


'This is the loop that goes through all the cells in the column
For each workingCell in workingRange.Cells

'... place your code here...

Next workingCell
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For integer constraints of some cells in the problem, just tell the solver like for instance: `SolverAdd CellRef:="$E$" & RowCount, Relation:=4, FormulaText:="integer"` When it comes to the looping, it works fine when I test it on presumably easier formulas. It could be the case that the solver only happens to find a solution for the last row. Try to have exactly the same parameters in all rows like you have in the last and be aware that you cannot always get a solution!